# logging mysql queries with mamp 2.0.1 wont work

Tags: mamp, mysql

I have MAMP 2.0.1 which is the latest verison.
I copied the my-medium.cnf from /Applications/MAMP/Library/support-files 
then placed it in /Application/MAMP/Library and renamed it to my.cnf

under [mysql] i put log = /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_sql.log then saved
after i restarted apache/mysql i ran a few queries and nothing shows up. I tried by not creating the log file and with the log file. no matter what i do the queries wont get logged. Has something changed in MAMP 2.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP PRO, open File > Edit template > MySQL my.cnf

In [mysqld] section write:

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/Applications/MAMP/logs/<some-file>.log
```

Then restart MAMP.

I'm using MAMP Pro 2.1.1 with MySQL 5.5.25.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the entry needs to be in `[mysqld]`, not `[mysql]`

Comment: what is the difference between mysql and mysqld ?

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html: "For example, the [mysqld] and [mysql] groups apply to the mysqld server and the mysql client program, respectively."